# Regexp matching separated proxy ip and port

Tags: regex, proxy

I am trying to scrape some proxy address from websites. I never learn regex in deep. There are a few common formats and here's the regex i am using

```
Regex ip = new Regex(@"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(?:\t*)(?: *)(?::*)(\d{2,5})");
```

Different website uses different format, could be 8.8.8.8\t\t 80, 8.8.8.8:80, 8.8.8.8  \t80

This regex is able to capture most of the address but obviously it will mismatch 123.123.123.123 into ip 123.123.123.1 and port 23 if the ip address is not followed by port separated by one of the three elements

I want the three common element \t,space,: to be zero or more but at least one of the three appears.

I think of negative lookahead but I am too noob to make a good use.

Any suggesion?

Comment: So is `::` also ok? I guess all you want is: `(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})[ \t]*:?[ \t]*(\d{2,5})` or shorter `(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s*:?\s*(\d{2,5})`.

Comment: Most of the time only one : will appear. (?::*) can be changed to (?::?) but it doesnt make big difference in grabbing the right address. I guess I didn't ask detailed enough , sorry, I edited the question to make less confusion.

Comment: You added semicolon `;` as separator in samples, but in question you don't mention it, should we consider it?

Comment: Sorry , its a typo. The question can be simplify to how to have three zero or more character but at least one of the character appear , else do not match it

Comment: You can use the followings: `(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})[ \t:]+(\d{2,5})`, `(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})[\s:]+(\d{2,5})` - these would also match ip/ports like `123.123.123.123:: :: ::80`.

Comment: It works! It seems that its not a hard expression. Obviously I am too noob. Please leave a answer so I can select it.

Comment: I dont know if I can ask another simple question in comment section. May you tell me the difference between [] and () in C# regex? I find that sometimes [] cannot match and I have to change it to ()

Comment: `[]` - any character of the set, ex. `[abc]` - will match `a`, `b`, `c`, `[abc]+` will match all combinations like `a`, `b`, `c`, `aa`, `ab`, `ac`, ... , but `()` - capturing group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are ok with addresses like `123.123.123.123 :    ::  : 80`, then you can use the following:

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})[ \t:]+(\d{2,5})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

If you want to match only addresses like `123.123.123.123 : 80`, `123.123.123.123 80`, `123.123.123.123:80` (max one `:`), then you can lookahead.

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(?=[^\d])\s*:?\s*(\d{2,5})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Or you can use `or` operation:

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(?:\s+|\s*:\s*)(\d{2,5})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: It is quite difficult to search regular expression symbol meaning in google. May I know the meaning of (?=) in the second expression?

Comment: @IsoletChan It is positive lookahead - http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html.